# View model binding in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, data-binding, model-binding

I am trying to make two way binding between model and view using protocols.
I did it by creating 3 protocols:
BoundableView.swift

```
protocol BoundableView {
    var updater: ViewModelUpdater? {get set}
}
```

BoundableModel.swift

```
protocol BoundableModel {
    var updater: ViewModelUpdater? {get set}
}
```

ViewModelUpdater.swift

```
protocol ViewModelUpdater {
    func updateModel(view: BoundableView)
    func updateView(model: BoundableModel)
}
```

and then conform these protocols in MVC classes

View.swift

```
class View: UIView,BoundableView {

    var updater :ViewModelUpdater? = nil

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var valueTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    updater?.updateModel(view: self)
    }
}
```

Model.swift

```
class Model : BoundableModel{
    var updater: ViewModelUpdater? = nil

    var name:String {
        didSet {
            if let updater = updater{
                updater.updateView(model: self)
                print(self)
            }
        }
    }
    var value:Int {
        didSet {
            if let updater = updater{
                updater.updateView(model: self)
                print(self)
            }
        }
    }
    init(name:String,value:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Controller.swift

```
class Controller: UIViewController,ViewModelUpdater {

    var boundableModel = Model(name : "hello", value: 5)

    @IBOutlet var boundableView: View!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        boundableModel.updater = self
        boundableView.updater = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    func updateModel(view: BoundableView) {
        let view = view as! View
        boundableModel.name = view.nameTextField.text!
        boundableModel.value = Int(view.valueTextField.text!)!

    }

    func updateView(model: BoundableModel) {
        let model = model as! Model
        boundableView.nameTextField.text = model.name
        boundableView.valueTextField.text = String(model.value)

    }
}
```

Problem comes when I want to bind for example table cell to model, because I don't know which cell is bound to which model in array. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The issue you'll encounter with TableViewCells is that they are 'reused'. The TableView controller only creates enough cells to fill it's view. As you scroll, the cells that disappear from the top are 'reused' back at the bottom (a bit like a conveyor belt). Due to the way they are designed, it's not really appropriate to bind each cell to a specific model element.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `UITableViews` you can hold an array of viewModels / updaters for all of the cells, even the ones that are not visible yet.

Depending on what data you need to populate your cell you might need to use some kind of cache mechanism if loading everything at once would hurt performance or would lead to a high memory usage, but that's specific for each case.

Some code to show what I mean:

```
class MyBindableCell: UITableViewCell, BoundableView {
    var updater: ViewModelUpdater? = nil
    //...
}

class Controller: UIViewController {

    var cellViewModels: [BoundableModel]
    var cellViewModelUpdaters: [ViewModelUpdater]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //...
        //initialize cellViewModels and viewModelUpdaters
        //...
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyBindableCell
        cell.updater = viewModelUpdaters[indexPath.row]
        cell.updater?.updateView(cellViewModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```